# How to use DoctrineCacheBundle

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

How to use DoctrineCacheBundle? I want to cache query (so that it is not translated to SQL each time, right?). Also I want to cache the result.

I have set it up like this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            cache_provider: metadata_cache
        query_cache_driver:
            cache_provider: query_cache
        result_cache_driver:
            cache_provider: result_cache
```

and

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        metadata_cache:
            apc: ~
        query_cache:
            apc: ~
        result_cache:
            apc: ~
```

And in my controller:

```
$cache = $this->get('doctrine_cache.providers.query_cache');
if ($cache->contains('someid')) {
    $surveysEntities = $cache->fetch('someid');
} else {
    $surveysEntities = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Survey')->getSurveys();
    $cache->save('someid', $surveysEntities);
}
```

This will cache only query? Or both query and result? Is it enough? OR I should also do sth on query in my repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. This cache result. Query is cached with doctrine via config. settings.